# How to I move my javascript resources into a local folder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I wrote a small app using **laravel 5.2**. I tried to keep all of my code in one folder located outside the app folder.

I created a folder called `modules`. Inside the `modules` folder I have a folder for vendor name. Then, inside the vendor folder, I have a module folder which contains my code.

Here is a simple folder structure

```
app modules/vendor name/module name/...
```

I managed to move my controllers, views and a route file into the module name folder.

How would I move all of the javascripts located in the public folder into my module name folder so that everything inside is in the same folder?

Additionally, I have a lot of questions about the views being in the module folder. Is it a better practice to use `$this->publishes()` to publish views to the resources/views folder that comes with laravel? If so what are the benefits?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit to publishing the views is that the end user, should they want/need to, then has the option to modify the views.

As for the javascript, its completely fine to contain the javascript in your modules folders as the docs mention. You have 2 options as to how they're then used. You can either choose to publish them which moves them into the public folder, or you can include them in your build process if you use elixir/gulp, etc. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/packages#public-assets

Edit:

To publish assets such as javascript files (they could in theory be anything, be that images, css, etc.) use the following from your packages service provider.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '/path/to/script.js' => public_path('vendor/my-package'),
        __DIR___ . '/path/to/another.js' => public_path('vendor/my-package'),
    ]);
}
```

The above will move both `script.js` and `another.js` into the `/public/vendor/my-package` folder. Just to explain `__DIR__` is a PHP 'magic' constant which gives the directory the current php file is located in and `public_path()` is a Laravel function which gives us the location of the `/public` folder as some users choose to rename this folder to their specific configuration.

Comment: But wouldn't the user have the option to still edit the views even if they were not published? I am still a bit not clear on why it is beneficial. Regarding the JS, the docs is showing how to publish them but I am not sure if I missed how would I tell laravel were the location of the assets.

Comment: They do and don't. Whilst yes you can edit things under the /vendor folder, as soon as you install or update, all your changes to anything there get overwritten. By "publishing" the views into their own code they then have control over what updates get applied and if they have made modifications they can manually update their views with any changes that may need to be applied. I've updated my answer to address your query about the js.

Comment: Thank you.  Thank makes more since now. And for the code you posted, I can also copy a folder instead of a file too using the same code?

Comment: Yup you can publish an entire folder too, just omit the file from the path. e.g `__DIR__ . '/path/to/folder' => public_path('vendor/my-package')`